# check_snmp plugin timedout icinga2

Tags: nagios, icinga2, check-snmp

I am new to icinga, and at the moment I am trying to monitor a paloalto firewall running paOS 9.0 with OID 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2.1 (hrProcessorLoad.1), but I have problems with the check_snmp plugin that is costantly timing out and I don't know why; I tryied everything.
the system is running:

- SO: centos 7
- Icinga2 Version 2.11.3-1
- IcingaWeb2 Version 2.7.3
- Icinga director module Version  1.7.2

the version of the check_snmp plugin is 2.3.3

the command runned by icinga and the associeted error are

```
[root@icinga-test plugins]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_snmp -C <community> -H 10.200.145.77 -c 50 -m HOST-RESOURCES-MIB -o hrProcessorLoad.1 -t 10 -w 40
CRITICAL - Plugin timed out while executing system call
```

even if use nuemrical OID instead of the name, the result won't change

I know that is not a network problem because a snmpget show this:

```
[root@icinga-test plugins]# snmpget -v2c -c <comunity> 10.200.145.77 hrProcessorLoad.1
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrProcessorLoad.1 = INTEGER: 7
```

the fact that it's working with the should also tell that the MIB are correctly installed,
also, I trtied to increase the timeout parameter up to 120 second and nothing changed

the very strange thing is the that same plugin is correctly monitring other centos 7 system with OID .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.2.1.5.1, and it never timedout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missing the protocol switch -P2c
https://nagios-plugins.org/doc/man/check_snmp.html

Comment: thank you for your answer, now it's working correctly